# Split and copy a file from a bucket to another bucket, without downloading it locally

Tags: shell, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, filesplitting

I'd like to **split** and copy a huge file from a bucket (`gs://$SRC_BUCKET/$MY_HUGE_FILE`) to another bucket (`gs://$DST_BUCKET/`), but **without downloading the file locally**. I expect to do this using only `gsutil` and shell commands.

I'm looking for something with the same final behaviour as the following commands :

```
gsutil cp gs://$SRC_BUCKET/$MY_HUGE_FILE my_huge_file_stored_locally

split -l 1000000 my_huge_file_stored_locally a_split_of_my_file_

gsutil -m mv a_split_of_my_file_* gs://$DST_BUCKET/
```

But, because I'm executing these actions on a Compute Engine VM with limited disk storage capacity, getting the huge file locally is not possible (and anyway, it seems like a waste of network bandwidth).

The file in this example is split by number of lines (`-l 1000000`), but I will accept answers if the split is done by number of bytes.

I took a look at the docs about [streaming uploads and downloads using gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming#streaming_uploads_and_downloads_using_gsutil) to do something like :

```
gsutil cp gs://$SRC_BUCKET/$MY_HUGE_FILE - | split -1000000 | ...
```

But I can't figure out how to upload split files directly to `gs://$DST_BUCKET/`, without creating them locally (creating temporarily only 1 shard for the transfer is OK though).

Comment: Have you considered using Storage Transfer Service? That's exactly what it's meant for: https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/overview#what_is

Comment: I am aware that Storage Transfer Service could be used to transfer files from a bucket to another bucket, but here I want to split the file before copying it. I can't see any option in STS (https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/TransferSpec) to split input files.

Comment: Understood. Is it necessary for you to manually do the split/compose? As you can just enable multi-threading for gsutil, or use parallel uploading: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/transferring-big-data-sets-to-gcp#transfer_from_colocation_or_on-premises_storage

Comment: Unfortunately, files in the destination bucket must have a maximum number of lines (1 000 000), or at least a maximum size (10MB) : fulfilling any of these 2 conditions is OK for me though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can't be done without downloading, but you could use range reads to build the pieces without downloading the full file at once, e.g.,

```
gsutil cat -r 0-10000 gs://$SRC_BUCKET/$MY_HUGE_FILE | gsutil cp - gs://$DST_BUCKET/file1
gsutil cat -r 10001-20000 gs://$SRC_BUCKET/$MY_HUGE_FILE | gsutil cp - gs://$DST_BUCKET/file2
...
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. So it seems like splitting a file by a specific number of lines is not possible, can you confirm this?

Comment: You could write some code (e.g., on GCE or App Engine) to do what you're asking for. But given the constraint of using gsutil, no, it's not possible.